# Does a thread own a mutex after pthread_cond_timedwait times out?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix, condition-variable

After a thread calls `pthread_cond_timedwait`, and it returns `ETIMEDOUT`, does the thread own the mutex?

I would initially think NO, but it appears that we *must* call `pthread_mutex_unlock` even after `pthread_cond_timedwait` returns `ETIMEDOUT`.

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) says:

> Upon successful return, the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread.

So, upon nonsuccessful return (return value != 0), the mutex is NOT owned, I would think.

But, if we do not call `pthread_mutex_unlock` after `ETIMEDOUT`, the mutex appears to be in a broken state (ie I cannot get another thread to acquire it, it just stalls).

The documentation also hints at this as well, as they *always* unlock the mutex regardless of the return value of `pthread_cond_timedwait`:

```
(void) pthread_mutex_lock(&t.mn);
                t.waiters++;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
        ts.tv_sec += 5;
        rc = 0;
        while (! mypredicate(&t) && rc == 0)
                rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&t.cond, &t.mn, &ts);
        t.waiters--;
        if (rc == 0) setmystate(&t);
(void) pthread_mutex_unlock(&t.mn);
```

So, does the thread ALWAYS acquire the mutex after `pthread_cond_timedwait`? It does not really make sense because the call would have to block more than the specificed time in order to acquire the mutex again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at an older issue of POSIX.  [Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) has this clarified text:

> When such timeouts occur, `pthread_cond_timedwait()` shall nonetheless release and re-acquire the mutex referenced by mutex, and may consume a condition signal directed concurrently at the condition variable.

If it didn't reacquire the mutex in this case you'd have to re-acquire it in the calling code anyway so you could re-test the condition after a timeout, because you might have consumed a condition signal. It's only if the condition you're waiting for hasn't occurred *and* a timeout occurred that you should treat it as the timeout case.

The timeout isn't guarding against the mutex being held for overly long, it's guarding against a condition signal not arriving in a timely manner (generally, the mutex should only be held for short, relatively deterministic periods whereas the condition being waited for might be influenced by external inputs).